# PostgreSQL not using index for NOT IN query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, performance, indexing

I've created two tables:

- `table1(id, cola, colb)` and
- `table2(id, cola, colb)`.

For both tables, I've defined a multi-column unique index on `cola` and `colb`. I created around 30 million rows in table1 and copied the same rows in table2. I then deleted around 60K rows in table2.

I wrote a query to get all rows from table1 that are `NOT IN` table2. Wondering why the query did not use the index (takes 37 seconds). Also, when I write the same query to get all rows from table1 that are `IN` table2, it runs a lot quicker (takes only 16 seconds).

I don't understand how indexes work very well, but I was wondering if someone can provide insights into what is going on.

**table1**

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
   id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   cola INTEGER NOT NULL,
   colb VARCHAR,
   
   CONSTRAINT unique_table1_cola_colb UNIQUE (cola, colb)
);
```

**table2**

```
CREATE TABLE table2 (
   id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   cola INTEGER NOT NULL,
   colb VARCHAR,
   
   CONSTRAINT unique_table2_cola_colb UNIQUE (cola, colb)
);
```

**Get row counts**

```
=> select count(*) from table1;
  count   
----------
 30000000
(1 row)

Time: 1010.109 ms (00:01.010)
=> 
=> select count(*) from table2;
  count   
----------
 29699970
(1 row)

Time: 1022.435 ms (00:01.022)
=>
```

**Get rows in table1 NOT IN table2: takes 37 seconds**

```
=> EXPLAIN ANALYSE
-> SELECT cola, colb
-> FROM table1
-> WHERE (cola, colb)
-> NOT IN (SELECT cola, colb
(>                FROM table2);
                                                                   QUERY PLAN                                                                    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Gather  (cost=534459.46..1440927.29 rows=1753542 width=15) (actual time=7505.507..37367.405 rows=300030 loops=1)
   Workers Planned: 2
   Workers Launched: 2
   ->  Parallel Hash Anti Join  (cost=533459.46..1264573.09 rows=730642 width=15) (actual time=7506.407..36919.080 rows=100010 loops=3)
         Hash Cond: (table1.cola = table2.cola)
         Join Filter: (((table1.colb)::text = (table2.colb)::text) OR (table2.colb IS NULL) OR ((table1.colb)::text IS NULL))
         Rows Removed by Join Filter: 143549855
         ->  Parallel Seq Scan on table1  (cost=0.00..316248.68 rows=12501468 width=15) (actual time=0.018..1351.725 rows=10000000 loops=3)
         ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=316211.98..316211.98 rows=12497798 width=15) (actual time=3735.958..3735.959 rows=9899990 loops=3)
               Buckets: 262144  Batches: 256  Memory Usage: 7840kB
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on table2  (cost=0.00..316211.98 rows=12497798 width=15) (actual time=0.013..1345.660 rows=9899990 loops=3)
 Planning Time: 0.861 ms
 Execution Time: 37382.576 ms
(13 rows)

Time: 37501.184 ms (00:37.501)
```

**Get rows in table1 NOT IN table2: takes 37 seconds**

```
=> EXPLAIN ANALYSE
-> SELECT cola, colb
-> FROM table1
-> WHERE (cola, colb)
-> IN (SELECT cola, colb
(>     FROM table2);
                                                                   QUERY PLAN                                                                    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Gather  (cost=565703.95..1130699.24 rows=29 width=15) (actual time=8322.403..14819.665 rows=29699970 loops=1)
   Workers Planned: 2
   Workers Launched: 2
   ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=564703.95..1129696.34 rows=12 width=15) (actual time=8312.194..12729.173 rows=9899990 loops=3)
         Hash Cond: ((table1.cola = table2.cola) AND ((table1.colb)::text = (table2.colb)::text))
         ->  Parallel Seq Scan on table1  (cost=0.00..316248.68 rows=12501468 width=15) (actual time=0.016..1366.878 rows=10000000 loops=3)
         ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=316211.98..316211.98 rows=12497798 width=15) (actual time=4142.989..4142.990 rows=9899990 loops=3)
               Buckets: 262144  Batches: 256  Memory Usage: 7552kB
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on table2  (cost=0.00..316211.98 rows=12497798 width=15) (actual time=0.013..1376.971 rows=9899990 loops=3)
 Planning Time: 0.399 ms
 Execution Time: 16136.308 ms
(11 rows)

Time: 16253.777 ms (00:16.254)
```

I was expecting the index to be used and also `NOT IN` and `IN` perform approximately the same.

Comment: Not that it makes a huge difference, but 30000000 - 29699970 = 300030. 300k, not 60k. Also, Postgres expects to find `rows=12497798`. Should be expecting close to 30M rows. Either there are just 12.5M rows, or you messed up a very basic statistic in the system. Please make the question consistent. And always declare your version of Postgres.

Comment: `Rows Removed by Join Filter: 143,549,855` and `loops=3`, that makes it a 320 million records that are removed. Something is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`NOT IN` cannot be optimized very well - besides harboring a logic trap for null values! Seeing that your `colb` can actually be null, [`NOT IN` is a bad idea](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_NOT_IN).

It's almost always better to use one of the other basic SQL techniques for this task. See:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

`NOT EXISTS` is often the best choice:

```sql
SELECT cola, colb
FROM   table1 t1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM table2 t2
   WHERE (t2.cola, t2.colb) = (t1.cola, t1.colb)
   );
```

(You still need to define how possible null values are supposed to be treated. Those slip through a basic `=` comparison.)

You'll see a much faster plan using index(-only) scans like:

```
'Merge Anti Join  (cost=11.30..1452575.86 rows=6764677 width=11)'
'  Merge Cond: ((t1.cola = t2.cola) AND ((t1.colb)::text = (t2.colb)::text))'
'  ->  Index Only Scan using unique_table1_cola_colb on table1 t1  (cost=0.56..577013.64 rows=30000032 width=11)'
'  ->  Index Only Scan using unique_table2_cola_colb on table2 t2  (cost=0.56..575877.16 rows=29939960 width=11)'
'JIT:'
'  Functions: 5'
'  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true'
```

That's the result of basic `EXPLAIN` in Postgres 16 for 30M rows with 60K missing with non-optimized settings.